# Can't Update function.php after writing short code

Tags: functions, actions

my initial `functions.php` is looks like this

```
<?php  
/**
 * SKT Charity functions and definitions
 *
 * @package SKT Charity
 */

global $content_width;
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
$content_width = 640; /* pixels */ 

// Set the word limit of post content 
function skt_charity_content($limit) {
$content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
if (count($content)>=$limit) {
array_pop($content);
$content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
} else {
$content = implode(" ",$content);
}   
$content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
return $content;
}

/**
 * Set the content width based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'skt_charity_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which runs
 * before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such as indicating
 * support post thumbnails.
 */
function skt_charity_setup() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'skt-charity', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
    add_theme_support('woocommerce');
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array( 'header-text' => false ) );
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'height'      => 350,
        'width'       => 150,
        'flex-height' => true,
    ) );
    add_image_size('skt-charity-homepage-thumb',240,145,true);
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'skt-charity' ),       
    ) );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array(
        'default-color' => 'ffffff'
    ) );
    add_editor_style( 'editor-style.css' );
} 
endif; // skt_charity_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'skt_charity_setup' );


function skt_charity_widgets_init() { 

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Blog Sidebar', 'skt-charity' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Appears on blog page sidebar', 'skt-charity' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '',      
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3><aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Header Left Widget', 'skt-charity' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Appears on left site of header', 'skt-charity' ),
        'id'            => 'header-info-left',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="headerinfo">',  
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',    
        'before_title'  => '<h3 style="display:none">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',     
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Header Right Widget', 'skt-charity' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Appears on right site of header', 'skt-charity' ),
        'id'            => 'header-info-right',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="headerinfo">',  
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',    
        'before_title'  => '<h3 style="display:none">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',     
    ) );


}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'skt_charity_widgets_init' );


function skt_charity_font_url(){
        $font_url = '';     

        /* Translators: If there are any character that are not
        * supported by Roboto, trsnalate this to off, do not
        * translate into your own language.
        */
        $roboto = _x('on','roboto:on or off','skt-charity');        


        /* Translators: If there has any character that are not supported 
        *  by Scada, translate this to off, do not translate
        *  into your own language.
        */
        $scada = _x('on','Scada:on or off','skt-charity');  

        if('off' !== $roboto ){
            $font_family = array();

            if('off' !== $roboto){
                $font_family[] = 'Roboto:300,400,600,700,800,900';
            }


            $query_args = array(
                'family'    => urlencode(implode('|',$font_family)),
            );

            $font_url = add_query_arg($query_args,'//fonts.googleapis.com/css');
        }

    return $font_url;
    }


function skt_charity_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('skt-charity-font', skt_charity_font_url(), array());
    wp_enqueue_style( 'skt-charity-basic-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'skt-charity-editor-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/editor-style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'nivoslider-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/nivo-slider.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'skt-charity-main-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/responsive.css' );       
    wp_enqueue_style( 'skt-charity-base-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style_base.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'skt-charity-nivo-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'skt-charity-custom_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js' );   

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'skt_charity_scripts' );

define('SKT_URL','https://www.sktthemes.net','skt-charity');
define('SKT_THEME_URL','https://www.sktthemes.net/themes','skt-charity');
define('SKT_THEME_DOC','https://sktthemesdemo.net/documentation/charity_documentation/','skt-charity');
define('SKT_PRO_THEME_URL','https://www.sktthemes.net/shop/charity-wordpress-theme/','skt-charity');
define('SKT_LIVE_DEMO','http://sktthemesdemo.net/charity/','skt-charity');
define('SKT_FEATURED_EMAGE','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=310YGYtGLIM','skt-charity');
define('SKT_FREE_THEME_URL','https://www.sktthemes.net/shop/skt-charity/','skt-charity');

/**
 * Implement the Custom Header feature.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

/**
 * Custom template for about theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/about-themes.php';

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Custom functions that act independently of the theme templates.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/extras.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

if ( ! function_exists( 'skt_charity_the_custom_logo' ) ) :
/**
 * Displays the optional custom logo.
 *
 * Does nothing if the custom logo is not available.
 *
 */
function skt_charity_the_custom_logo() {
    if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
        the_custom_logo();
    }
}
endif;

// Add a Custom CSS file to WP Admin Area
function skt_charity_admin_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-admin-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'skt_charity_admin_theme_style');
```

It works perfect in pc, but in mobile there is a problem in menu so I have added the code

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mobile_menu_script' );
function mobile_menu_script() {
 echo '<script>';
   echo 'jQuery(document).ready(function($){';
    echo '$('button.menu-toggle').click(function(){';
      echo 'if( $('button.menu-toggle').attr('aria-expanded') == 'true' ) {';
        echo '$('button.menu-toggle').attr('aria-expanded','false');';
        echo '$('ul#top-menu').attr('style','display:none;');';
      echo '}';
      echo 'else {';
        echo '$('button.menu-toggle').attr('aria-expanded','true');';
        echo '$('ul#top-menu').attr('style','display:block;');';
      echo '}';
    echo '});';
  echo '});';
echo '</script>';
}
```

and then I have updated the `functions.php` file now its blank. there is no output. please need help.

Comment: you can't use single quotes inside single quotes without escaping them (or use double quotes), in addition, you did not add script tags even though you are inserting inline js. but instead of all this, you should actually use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @motivast is correct. However, to avoid using a billion `echo` and apostrophes, you can simply close the PHP tag and open it after your script:

```
function wpse_287665_mobile_menu_script() { ?>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("button.menu-toggle").click(function(){
                if( $("button.menu-toggle").attr("aria-expanded") == "true" ) {
                    $("button.menu-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
                    $("ul#top-menu").attr("style", "display:none;");
                } else {
                    $("button.menu-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
                    $("ul#top-menu").attr("style","display:block;");
                }
            });
        });
    </script><?php
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_287665_mobile_menu_script' );
```

Neat, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

@inarolo has right. Your code should be looking like that:

```
function wpse_287665_mobile_menu_script() {

    echo '<script>';
        echo 'jQuery(document).ready(function($){';
            echo '$("button.menu-toggle").click(function(){';
                echo 'if( $("button.menu-toggle").attr("aria-expanded") == "true" ) {';
                    echo '$("button.menu-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "false");';
                    echo '$("ul#top-menu").attr("style", "display:none;");';
                echo '}';
                echo 'else {';
                    echo '$("button.menu-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "true");';
                    echo '$("ul#top-menu").attr("style","display:block;");';
                echo '}';
            echo '});';
        echo '});';
    echo '</script>';
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_287665_mobile_menu_script' );
```

Also, if you have blank page try to investigate first what is the problem enablling `WP_DEBUG` constant in your `wp-config.php` file.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress